# 2nd lvl slave can't conect to 1st lvl slave mysql replication

Tags: mysql, replication

Simple exercise but not working. Help me plase.

Context:
Lptp1, Lptp2 -> Ubuntu20.4 both

Lptp1 dbmaster, Lptp2 dbslavetwo, Lptp1 dvsubslave -> all Ver 8.0.24 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL) in dockers

Configs:

dbmaster my.cnf

```
server-id=1
log-bin=master-bin.log
binlog_format=mixed
max_binlog_size=50M
sync_binlog=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
expire_logs_days=14
report-host=dbmaster
```

dbslavetwo my.cnf

```
server-id=3
report-host=dbslavetwo
log-slave-updates=ON
log-bin=slavetwo-bin.log
#binlog_format=mixed
#max_binlog_size=50M
#sync_binlog=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
#expire_logs_days=14
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

dvsubslave my.cnf

```
server-id=4
report-host=dbsubslave
```

After command on dvsubslave

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='10.42.0.60',
MASTER_PORT=3555,
MASTER_USER='slaveuser',
MASTER_PASSWORD='1234',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='slavetwo-bin.000016',
MASTER_LOG_POS=156;
START SLAVE;
SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
```

Rceived: error connecting to master 'slaveuser@10.42.0.60:3555' - retry-time: 60 retries: 1 message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.42.0.60:3555' (111)

But in the same time replication Laptop1 dbmaster -> Laptop2 dbslavetwo works ok.

edit:

Topology : dbmaster -> dbslavetwo -> dvsubslave

ip:

| 10.42.0.60 -> Lptp2 with dbslavetwo (port: 3555)

| 10.42.0.1 -> Lptp1 with dbmaster, dvsubslave

Comment: Please state IP and port for each server.

Answer (score 0):

Which machine is `10.42.0.60`?  Why use port `3555`?

Your topology is this?

```
dbmaster -> dbslavetwo -> dvsubslave
```

Each is on a separate machine?  Then each could use the default port 3306.

Comment: yes, exactly - this is my intention :)
| 10.42.0.60 -> Lptp2 with dbslavetwo
| 10.42.0.1 -> Lptp1 with  dbmaster, dvsubslave